# Search a word in a particular area through elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have a requirement where I have to search a word in a particular position in the content through elastic search. For Example i have three records:

```
{
 "user": "apple",
 "postDate": "2011-12-13",
 "body": "ID: Hello\n Reference: Link to SH13",
 "title": "Documents"
} 
{
 "user": "apple",
 "postDate": "2011-11-14",
 "body": "ID: SH13\n Reference: Nothing SH186",
 "title": "Documents"
} 
{
 "user": "apple",
 "postDate": "2012-10-13",
 "body": "ID: Sample\n Reference: Nothing SH13",
 "title": "Documents"
}
```

If i try the below query, i get all the above records....

```
http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search?q=body:SH13&pretty=true
```

But i want to search which is in reference only without having a separate column for Reference in the database. I want the output to be only the below one when i search for 'SH13'(which is present in the Reference)

```
{
 "user": "apple",
 "postDate": "2011-12-13",
 "body": "ID: Hello\n Reference: Link to SH13",
 "title": "Documents"
}
{
 "user": "apple",
 "postDate": "2012-10-13",
 "body": "ID: Sample\n Reference: Nothing SH13",
 "title": "Documents"
}
```

I hope you understood the question... Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of "i want to search which is in reference only without having a separate row for Reference". From your example I could guess that you need to find documents that have `SH13` after `Reference` and not before, but I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an exact match of what you're trying to search. In your case the following query would get you only the second record:

```
http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search?q=body:"Reference: SH13"
```

**UPDATE**

If you know the reference will always be the last token of your `body` field and you want to search only for that, you can proceed as follows:

First, make your `body` field a multi-field with a `not_analyzed` sub-field:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/blog/_mapping/post -d '{
  "post": {
    "properties": {
      "body": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {         <--- we're adding this not_analyzed sub-field to the body field
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you need to re-index your data so that the `body.raw` sub-field gets populated.

And finally you'll be able to search for references appearing only at the end of your `body` field like this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/blog/post/_search?q=body.raw:/.*SH13/&analyze_wildcard=true&lowercase_expanded_terms=false
```

We're searching the `body.raw` field with the regexp `/.*SH13/` that specifies that the `SH13` token must be at the end of the field. Moreover, we're telling ES to analyze the wildcard character `*` (it does not by default) and to not lowercase the terms (it does by default).

Performing the three steps above will get you only the two documents you expect.

Comment: If i try that i know ill get the answer. ill refine my question

Comment: Is the reference you're looking for always the last term in the `body` field?

Comment: Should work if you followed all the steps I enumerated above. Make sure to re-index your data after changing your mapping.

Comment: Let me check and ill let you know... I really appreciate for the answer. Thanks